# Visual Studio Express 2013 Desktop: Watch Window Freezes And "The thread has exited with code 259"

Tags: visual-studio

I am new to developing Windows programs - when using Visual Studio Express for desktop and I click the "Start button" to run the app, a "Watch" window opens (several!) and then after closing the app, Visual Studio crashes (total freeze / unresp.)

I noticed that I also get a message the thread has exited with code 259 when running the app

Any idea what I am doing wrong? Can I disable the watch windows?

Comment: The windows are called "Watch 1", "Watch 2" etc - Watch 4 is on top and it freezes only after closing the running app

Comment: It very much looks like it is spawning loads of Watch windows

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have had this problem several times.  The last time it happened, I noticed that the tabs associated with Team Viewer 9 were rapidly flickering.  So, before I touched any of the Visual Studio Watch windows, I exited Team Viewer (completely shutting it down), and then I could close all the Watch windows.  Without it freezing. Then I shut VS down.  Then I restarted it, and I could debug without the watch windows showing up this time.

Comment: Now I have turned off the Team Viewer feature that puts those little tabs on all other forms (allowing one to access the "share this window" feature of Team Viewer) and the problem as not returned for many months.